# raw_input python repeat until it reaches a value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use `raw_input()`, until it reaches n. then it should stop.

`let number_pairs(n)`
and it prompts the user to enter values as many times as n, and then we will take the average.

so it looks like `raw_input(Enter value for number n:)`

and it starts at 1, and stops at n.

Comment: So what is the question? And what have you done so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything so far. I have trouble repeating raw_input process

Answer (score 3):

Get the values:

```
values = []
n = 10 #The input is 10 numbers
for i in range(n):
    values.append(float(raw_input("Enter value for number n: ")))
```

And compute the average:

```
average = sum(values) / len(values) #Turn it to float and do the math.
```

Comment: Float division? First of all, `raw_input` do not evaluate the input values, so what you have at hand is a list of strings and you can not even `sum` a list of strings. Beside that, if you have all int values in your list, then `sum` will be an `int` too... Dividing an `int` to another one is always `int`. So you better cast input values to `float` before appending them to your list.

Comment: Ah, i see. I missed that completely, sorry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also as I stated, OP asks for python 2.7. Still you have a list of `str` values in `values`. You must either `map` them to `float` or cast them to `float` before appending them to list.

Comment: Ok, np. Now you do not need to cast result of `sum` to float since all your values  in your list are all float.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the list of numbers from the user first, then get the average:

---

**If you want the user to enter as many numbers as he wants without specifying ahead of time:**

*Python 2.7+*

```
>>> numbers = list(iter(lambda: int(raw_input('Enter number (or 0 to finish): ')), 0))
```

*Python 3.+*

```
>>> numbers = list(iter(lambda: int(input('Enter number (or 0 to finish): ')), 0))
```

---

**If you want the user to specify the amount of numbers ahead of time:**

*Python 2.7+*

```
>>> numbers = [int(raw_input('Enter number: ')) for _ in range(int(raw_input('How many?: ')))]
```

*Python 3.+*

```
>>> numbers = [int(input('Enter number: ')) for _ in range(int(input('How many?: ')))]
```

---

**Once you have the numbers:**

```
>>> average = float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
```

Comment: this doesn't automatically stop at n

Comment: @user2956116 Now it does.